# Rust return "empty" generic variable

Tags: generics, rust

I want to have a function that let me extract infos from Results. The problem is what to return if something fails (the function uses a generic parameter). Here is my code :

```
fn check<T, E>(x: Result<T, E>) -> T {
    if let Ok(sk) = x {
        return sk;
    } else {
        println!("uh oh");
        return 0 as T;
    }
}
```

As you can guess it doesn't work, what should i put instead of `0 as T` ?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to return the default value for the type (0 for numbers, `false` for bools, an empty string for strings etc.) you can constrain it to `T: Default` and return `T::default()`:

```rust
fn check<T: Default, E>(x: Result<T, E>) -> T {
    if let Ok(sk) = x {
        return sk;
    } else {
        println!("uh oh");
        return T::default();
    }
}
```

But note that there is an existing method on `Result` that returns the default value in case of `Err`: [`unwrap_or_default()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.unwrap_or_default).